# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis when creating a table

Tags: oracle, ddl

I have the below query that works fine and produces the correct result

```
select id, sum(item_stock)
from seller
group by id
order by id ASC;
```

When I try to create a table with the query above like this

```
CREATE TABLE total_stock
AS (
select id, sum(item_stock)
from seller
group by id
order by id ASC );
```

I get the following error

SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Any help on why this isn't working would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the clause **ORDER BY**.

You have to:

1. Add an alias to your "sum" field
2. Create another subquery in order to "remove" the **ORDER BY** clause

> ```
> CREATE TABLE total_stock
> AS (
>     select id, item_stock
>     from (
>          select id, sum(item_stock) as item_stock
>          from seller
>          group by id
>          order by id ASC 
>          )
> )
> ```

Comment: Unrelated, but: the parentheses around the outer select (after the `AS`) are useless - and you don't really need the derived table at all (the inner select). And the `order by` is useless as well as a table has no order to begin with. The  statement can be simplified to `CREATE TABLE total_stock
AS
select id, sum(item_stock) as item_stock
from seller
group by id;`